# jquery mobile making external xml file also available offline

Tags: jquery, xml, mobile, web-applications

I created an app wiht phonegap that reads xml data for a urs (data from a website database).
I would like to create an offline copy of this xml that is parsed whenever there's no internet connection and update it whenever an internet connection is available.

Can somebody help me out.